# Wordpress REST API: Get raw database content

Tags: wordpress, api

I want to pull data from my event calender. So I added REST API support to my event content type. But my JSON output is with HTML.

Can I not get the raw database data?

I get this: http://astc.dk/wp-json/wp/v2/event/

I put this in my functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_event_cpt', 25 );
function my_event_cpt() {
  global $wp_post_types;

  //be sure to set this to the name of your post type!
  $post_type_name = 'event';
  if( isset( $wp_post_types[ $post_type_name ] ) ) {
    $wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->show_in_rest = true;
    // Optionally customize the rest_base or controller class
    $wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->rest_base = $post_type_name;
    $wp_post_types[$post_type_name]->rest_controller_class = 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller';
  }
}
```

Comment: What you have tried and what you are looking for, please provide code also?

Comment: I get this: http://astc.dk/wp-json/wp/v2/event/

Comment: you can write custom REST API?

Comment: How do i connect to a custom table with the rest api? Can anyone show an exsample?